# Adding Cloudformation Stack Events to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to add a cloudformation stack to an sns notification from within the template.  I'd like for users not to have to remember to select notification settings when launching the stack.

Alternatively can I register the stack with sns after the fact using the cli?  Possibly could do it when the instance launches in my UserData script.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can definitely create an SNS Topic in CloudFormation (using AWS::SNS::Topic ), and you can also add CloudWatch Alarms (using AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm ) which can then trigger SNS topics (either an existing one or one that you create in the CF template) by passing it in with the AlarmActions property.

Comment: I would to add event notifications in some way that doesn't require a user to remember to set it up correctly in the aws ui.    I need to be made aware of stack terminations so I can cleanup some external resources, but my users may not remember to add it when creating their stack.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to directly specify the SNS Topic of the Cloud Formation template, but one (less ideal) option would be to nest your desired CloudFormation template in another CloudFormation template, because the AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Resource type allows you to specify the SNS Topic (see [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html)) with the [NotificationARNs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-notificationarns) property.

Comment: That might be an option,    the real crux of the problem is that we don't actually let users use cloud formation.  They actually use service catalog  which doesn't allow a way to set an sns topic at all.

Comment: Ah.  Yeah, that's a different problem.

Comment: Create SNS in SAM template. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html